# Use CloneZilla to upgrade notebook disk

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, 15.10, clonezilla, cloning

I would like to replace the 500GB HD of my Kubuntu 15.10 notebook by a new 1TB disk. To avoid reinstalling the (relatively fresh) system I want to clone the disk using CloneZilla.

This is what I found: http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone

Sounds easy. However the link doesn't answer two questions:

1. Appart from two non-encrypted partitions (/boot and /boot/efi) there is a root partition that is LUKS enycrypted (EXT4 on LVM2 on LUKS if understood correctly). Does this make any difference regarding the cloning process described by the above link?
2. I would like to utilize the additional 500GB of the new disk. I suppose after cloning, half of the new disk is unused. I probably should fill the space by increasing the size of my root partition. What is the easiest way (possibly using GUI)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know specifically what filesystems the newest clonezilla supports, however, for non-known file systems it will use a sector to sector copy with DD.  While, it will be much slower than clonezilla's own mechanism for cloning, it will make a replica regardless of type.

*If Clonezilla fails, you can opt to clone the drive using dd directly.  It can take much longer to do but will ignore file system types.

> **Clone a Drive**
>
> Clone the contents of a whole hard drive onto another completely different drive.  You need to do this while booting a live disc, you will need the drives unmounted.
>
> if=source and of=destination

Be extra careful and check the command over before submitting it.  Having the input and output parameters incorrectly set would be very bad.

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

After you clone to the larger drive, depending on how the partitions are setup, you may be able to run a live ubuntu disc, and use gparted to grow the partition.  I have difficulties saying with certainty as the location of the partition will make a difference.  If the partition you plan to grow is between other partitions it will technically have nowhere to grow.  If it's the last partition you should have no problems.

Comment: It is the last partition. I will try and see what happens.

Comment: It does not work. Everything looks ok but CloneZilla tells me that there is some error when creating a partition table on the destination disk. Unfortunately it doesn't tell me any details.

Comment: Did you write down any specific error code?

Comment: No error code. It says "Error when creating partition table..." (in german) and asks if the target disk is too small (which isn't true). Nothing else. Later is says "/dev/sdb: recognize disc label" (which is the target disc) and shows secondary errors while trying to access the three non-existing partitions.

Comment: I updated my answer to include using dd, and not using clonezilla.